# Datatables column search elements inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to search the labels inside a specific column of a datatable.

[image: what my table looks like]

My html:

```
<td width="180">
  <label for="" class="hide">{{$bli->status->name}}</label>
  <form action="/items" method="POST">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
    <select name="status_id" class="form-control status" id="sel1">
      @foreach($status as $stat)
      <option {{ $stat->id == $bli->status->id ? "selected" : "" }} value="{{ $stat->id }}">{{ $stat->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </form>
</td>
```

The labels are hidden and only a drop down select is shown per table-cell.
I want to look for the text inside the hidden labels.

```
var table=$('.dataTable').DataTable();
$(".dataTable tfoot th").each(function(i) {
  if($(this).hasClass('status')) {
    var isStatusColumn=(($(this).hasClass('status')) ? true : false);
    var column=table.column(i);

    var select=$('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($(this).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val=$(this).val();
        table.column(i)
          .search(val ? '^'+$(this).val()+'$' : val, true, false)
          .draw();
        console.log(table.column(i));
      });


    if(isStatusColumn) {
      var statusItems=[];

      table.column(i).nodes().to$().each(function(d, j) {

        var thisStatus=$(j).find("label").html();
        if($.inArray(thisStatus, statusItems)=== -1) statusItems.push(thisStatus);
      });

      statusItems.sort();

      $.each(statusItems, function(i, item) {
        select.append('<option value="'+item+'">'+item+'</option>');
      });
    }
    // All other non-Status columns (like the example)
    else {
      table.column(i).data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find any labels and instead gives me a message such as:

[image]

How can I specify the `table.column( i ).search` to search for the labels inside of the td's?  I have tried to just use `table.column( i ).search( val )` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution on my own.

For anyone interested:

```
$(".dataTable thead th").each( function ( i ) {
    if($(this).hasClass('status')){
        var column = table.column( i );

        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').on( 'change', function () {

            var listOfVals = [];

            $("thead input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index, element){
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    var val = $(this).parent().find("label").html();
                    listOfVals.push(val);
                }
            })
            var vals = listOfVals.join('|');
            column
              .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
        } );
    }
} );
```

I replaced the select with checkboxes instead (select checkbox combo if you like) and hardcoded them instead of appending them to the dom with JS. 
Made an array of the value of each selected checkbox onChange and pushed the array to the datatable search value.
It's now working as it should.